# Styling for Sir Trevor CSS not displaying correctly Ruby On Rails App

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sirtrevor

I'm trying to implement an online text editor that allows people to create and write blogs. I saw that SirTrevor has a really slick UI and I'm really keen on using it.

I've managed to get it working technically based [on these instructions](https://github.com/madebymany/sir-trevor-rails), but the UI is simply not there; Everything is simply in text, no icons or anything. I'm looking to get something similar to the [example](http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/example.html) listed on their website. I've installed the Ruby on Rails Gem, and used Bower Install to get the files I need in my Vendor/Assets folder. Both the CSS and JS files appear to be loading (I can see their rules).

When I compare the source code of the provided example with mine, I do not have any SVG elements, and I'm wondering if there is something extra I need to do here

My code is as follows:

**blogs.coffee:**

```
SirTrevor.setDefaults({
    iconUrl: '/assets/images/sir-trevor-icons.svg'
})
editor = new SirTrevor.Editor({
    el: $('.sir-trevor-area'),
    defaultType: 'Text'
});
```

The documentation advises us to use `document.querySelector("...")` instead of jQuery, but that renders even worse results - just a plain text area

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form.text_area :main_body, {:class=>"sir-trevor-area"}%>
```

Comment: Try getting the resource using the `asset_path` helper `<%= asset_path 'sir-trevor-icons' %>`

Comment: Thanks, I think this is one part of the problem. Still not working though

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Sir Trevor assets to Rails assets. Inside `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  sir-trevor/build/sir-trevor-icons.svg
)
```

The path could vary depending on Sir Trevor installation method, I installed it with `yarn` without using the gem at all. Anyway just locate the right path on your installation.

Comment: Ok, So now I am able to view the icons if I use the following code <svg class="icon gr-menu">
          <use xlink:href="<%= asset_path('sir-trevor-icons') %>#quote"></use>
        </svg>. I assume this means that my Pre-compilation is working as expected, but the sir-trevor text area is still not working as desired

Comment: What do you mean with "sir-trevor text area is still not working as desired"? What do you expect and what does it happen instead?

Comment: I expect the output in the example linked in the OP. But I get functionally working, without correct styles (visually almost like plain text) applied. Each Block Type just has text links that you can click and the block will be added. It is not using the icons provided in the SVG. That said the CSS is loading ( I see styles applied in the DOM inspector) but the SVG elements in the linked example above are not being generated

Comment: I'm wondering now if there is a clash between some of my gems, or maybe some sort of version issue...

Comment: If you check the Network tab on your browser Developer Tools you should see a 404 related to Sir Trevor SVG not found. That's a good start.

Comment: I have tried in two scenarios 1. With purely the code for Sir trevor. The SVG does not appear in the Networks Tab AND 2. With an additional SVG element on the page (same code as comment #1 above). Response Status Code is 200 OK and Content Type image/svg+xml. Response and Preview are both empty

Comment: No clue. Anyway, this was my Sir Trevor initializer file: https://gist.github.com/mdesantis/2c737cbd738c9acf3828618b3f3b4304 You could check if it helps

Comment: Still no luck... I've tried to take my mind out of the problem for a while and get stuck back in there later...